# How to convert UISlider and accelerometer data to 16 bit char HEX in xcode/Objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, type-conversion, uislider

I need to convert an UISlider value and my iPhones accelerometer data to a char in format `char hexData = {0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0xA0}`. Any ideas on this? 
The accelerometer values are signed (positive and negative) numbers, while the UISlider value spans from 0 to 100.

Thank you

Comment: are you looking to create a char array?  or do you want char as a 4-byte value?

Comment: I think both would work. I just need to send 4 byte as hex

Comment: without knowing exactly what you're looking for, it sounds like you to do nothing more than simple casting, since you're only convertin numbers to numbers ... which makes me wonder what it is i don't understand about your question.

Comment: Well, I am new at this, so maybe my question makes less sense than it should, but I am reading an appnote, telling me that data to be sent should be a char array. When I have e.g a number of one byte I only need to add 3 preceding 0-value bytes, but if my integer extends to two or three bytes, I only need to add one or two preceding bytes of zero. Hope you understand what I am trying to, but please tell me if I you think I am wrong in how I attack this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, i don't know what endianness the data is expected to be sent in; you may have to reverse the order.

but you should be able to get away with simple C manipulations such as the following.

```
    char fourChar[4];
    int* value = (int*)(&fourChar);
    *value = (int)floatValueFromSlider;  // or the simple values from your picker
    [appNote sendCharArray:fourChar];    // assuming the method wants a char[] of only 4 characters
```

this will be in little-endian format.  you will probably have to swap the bytes before sending, depending upon what the receiver expects.  you can manipulate this further as necessary.